# Javascript:Saving the SVG element in local file system as a PNG and Copy to clipboard does not work

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 chart.  I have couple issues.

**1. Save as PNG**

I am trying to save this SVG element in a PNG format on click of hyperlink "Save as PNG". Instead of saving the image  , I see only empty content. I am not sure if it is because of the class etc.

```
 d3.select("#download").on("click", function () {
       debugger;
       d3.select(this)
        .attr("href", 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa(d3.select("#line").html()))
        .attr("download", "test.png")
     })
```

**2. Save to Clipboard**

Copy to clipboard does  not work.

The code is in the below URL: Can you please help me.

```
     //clipboard
 d3.select("#clipboard").on("click", function () {
     debugger;
     var div = document.getElementById('line1');
     div.contentEditable = 'true';
     var controlRange;
     if (document.body.createControlRange) {
         controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
         controlRange.addElement(div);
         controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
     }
     div.contentEditable = 'false';
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shanthisivanesan/VGTz3/7/

Comment: Try to render SVG to Image() or canvas before serializing data into string.